# routing problem in express.js with html and hbs view engine

Tags: node.js, express

```
  router.get('/dist/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

my app.js routing code

```
app.set('dist', path.join(__dirname, 'dist'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
```

my folder structure

`root/dist/index.html`

I cannot open this page on my first page

how can I open this page? Where is my mistake?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `set()` to redefine express's default settings.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/dist'));
```

Working Example

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const port = 3000;

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
// Set 'views' directory for any views 
// being rendered res.render()
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/dist'));

// Set view engine
app.engine('html', require('hbs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use('/', indexRouter);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/dist/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Inside Dist Folder Index' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I have an error:     Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\Users\-GT-\temadeneme\dist"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\-GT-

Comment: please send your folder structure

Comment: my index inside temadeneme/dist/index.html

my app.js  inside temadeneme/app.js

Comment: try adding `../dist` or `./`

Comment: try adding `../dist` or `./dist`. Im not actually getting your path